# Set static colors in app. Colors cannot change in various device OS

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to set colors specially in my application.

For a example if i add a ProgressBar in my application and set a color with `android:indeterminateTint="#BDBDBD"` (Gray). This can not be change.

It doesn't matter the device or theme the progress bar color should be `#BDBDBD`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a global declarable style which can be placed in **style.xml**. Add a `android:progressBarStyle`in your parent style that is used by all of the activities.

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/CustomProgressBar</item>
    </style>
```

Make the progress bar customizations here,

```
<style name="CustomProgressBar" parent="android:Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
      <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
      <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_progress_bar_horizontal</item>
      <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
      <item name="android:maxHeight">20dip</item>
    </style>
```

Now your progress bar style should be applied in all of the activities.

Check the official demos code here,

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml